# Can I browse a folder which resides in a virtual machine from the host machine?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, vmware-player

I have a repository of files in a virtual machine, which is stuck at Windows XP SP2. I am forced to use a version of a program (Subversion) with these files which cannot be installed pre-SP3. My host OS is Windows 7. So I thought I might be able to install svn on the host, and then act on the files within the guest, via some shared folder or some such between the guest and the host. Sharing a host folder within the guest seems easy.

But how can I share a folder which resides within the guest machine, for the host OS to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on file sharing, or if you are using VirtualBox, it has shared folders (natively, shared with only the host) if you install the virtualbox extensions.

Comment: Forgive me: where should the folder appear on the host? I can't see it. I am using VMware Player 5; are there any network adapter settings required in the VM Settings? Should the host adapters be set in any way (VMnet0, 1 and/or 8)? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, let's try this again.  In the virtual machine, turn on WINDOWS file sharing , i.e. right click the folder and pick "Share".  Once that's done, you should be able to find \\VIRTUALSERVERNAME\SHARENAME from the host.  Can't really help much on any vmware-specific features, sorry!

Comment: In the guest, the folder is Shared, and for now Full Control is given to Everyone on it. The VM's three network adapters are set to Host Only, NAT, and Host only. All are Connected.
In the host, file and printer sharing is switched on for both "Home or Work" and "Domain".
I still see nothing shared in Network. Where should I look?

Comment: Use ipconfig to find the ip address of either host-only adapter in the VM. (the nat adapter won't work.)  Then, on the host, press Windows-R, and type \\[address]\sharename and click OK.  The share may not show up on a network browse on the host at all, but this approach will work as long as the other stuff is configured correctly.

Comment: Are you opening the network window and waiting for it to show up or have you tried using UNC


`\\<hostname or IP>\<share name>`

eg. if the host ip is 192.168.1.10 and the share name is "shared".

`\\192.168.1.10\shared`

Comment: The latter. Curiously, from the host I can ping the IP which the guest reports it has, but in the host I can't browse to `\\<IP>\<share name>` using Windows Explorer. I get "Network Error" with "unspecified error" as more details.

Comment: Turn off Windows firewall on the VM.

Comment: It's already off. But now I have some connectivity, because I can see `http://<IP>` with IE on the host. I'm now getting a Logon failure with `\\<IP>\<share name>`, which may be because blank passwords are not allowed...anyway that's a different problem, so, query answered, thanks for your help.